# Optimize Query - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, optimization

**Problem:**

I have been working on the HackerRank Challenge [15 Days of Learning SQL](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem?isFullScreen=false) (*The problem statement can be found at the link that I provided*). After looking over it a bit I know you can usually replace sub queries with joins. I was hoping I could get help replacing the sub queries with join.

**MS SQL Server Script:**

```
WITH 
  unique_hackers_on_dates AS
(
   SELECT   
      Submissions.submission_date,
      Submissions.hacker_id,
      COUNT(1) subs_per_hacker_per_day,
      MAX(COUNT(1)) OVER (PARTITION BY submission_date) max_subs_per_day
   FROM
      Submissions
   GROUP BY
      Submissions.submission_date,
      Submissions.hacker_id      
), 
   hacker_with_max_sub AS
(
   SELECT
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date,
      MIN(hacker_id) min_hacker_id
   FROM
      unique_hackers_on_dates
   WHERE
      unique_hackers_on_dates.subs_per_hacker_per_day = unique_hackers_on_dates.max_subs_per_day
   GROUP BY
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date
), 
   dates AS
(
   SELECT   
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date, 
      unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id
   FROM
      unique_hackers_on_dates
   WHERE
      unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date = CAST('2016-03-01' AS Date)
   UNION ALL
      SELECT   
         unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date, 
         unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id
      FROM     
         dates
      INNER JOIN
         unique_hackers_on_dates 
         ON dates.hacker_id = unique_hackers_on_dates.hacker_id AND
            DATEADD(DAY, 1, dates.submission_date) = unique_hackers_on_dates.submission_date
), 
   consec_hackers as
(
   SELECT 
      submission_date,
      count(1) num_consec_hackers
   FROM 
      dates
   GROUP BY
      submission_date
)
SELECT
   consec_hackers.submission_date,
   consec_hackers.num_consec_hackers,
   hacker_with_max_sub.min_hacker_id,
   Hackers.name
FROM
   consec_hackers
INNER JOIN
   hacker_with_max_sub
   on consec_hackers.submission_date = hacker_with_max_sub.submission_date
INNER JOIN
   Hackers 
   ON hacker_with_max_sub.min_hacker_id = Hackers.hacker_id
ORDER BY 
    consec_hackers.submission_date;
```

**Question:**

Can I get help changing the script to use joins instead of using sub queries?

Also will the above fix be the most efficient solution?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view) and 
 
 [**How do I obtain a Query Execution Plan?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan)

Comment: Why you mean replace subqueries with joins? Looks like you need do separated calculation to get the values you need to join later

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am unable to get an exact execution time though hackerrank.com. I just have always been wary of using sub queries because I know they can bog down scripts execution time and I've been told before that sub queries can usually be substituted for joins. This is why I was hoping I could get some help.

Comment: What subqueries do you want to replace?   Are you conflating subqueries with CTEs?

Comment: @TabAlleman No I dont have any in my CTEs but I do a few unions that I feel might be able to be updated or changed. I guess me more generic question is, from the best of your knowledge how can I optimize this query?

Comment: That is too broad. Sometimes is already optimal. Sometime the biggest improvement is from an index. That is why we required some stats first to have a baseline of what is the current performance.If you want code review we have https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: CTEs vs. subqueries vs. joins often don't matter. The optimizer readily converts most things that boil down to joins to joins, while things that can't be converted that way typically *need* the subquery. If you have no concrete perf numbers on this query and/or no way to get execution plans, there's no point to optimizing it. I've seen some fiendishly clever rewrites of queries that accomplished precisely nothing because the optimizer produced the exact same plan.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you! That does help give some insight on what actaully going on behind the scenes with joins vs. CTEs vs. subquerys

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry, I've seens ome pretty broad questions on here so I thought this one would make the cut, but thank you! I will look into that!